# Правильное редактирование, удаление, копирование данных через чекбокс

Tags: php, html, javascript

мое почтение! у меня к Вам большая просьба!
стоит задача сделать примерно вот такое (не могу загрузить изображение, к сожалению):

1. выводятся все элементы из БД (задача решена);
2. Редактирование элемента при нажатии на ячейку(задача решена);
3. каждый элемент можно выбрать checkbox для целей массового Удаления выбранных элементов или для выгрузки в подготовленный документ .doc

В связи с этим у меня сложились вопросы: как устроить удаление? весь вывод сделать в форме, чтобы подсчитать checkbox?
какие средства мне потребуются, для того чтобы выгрузить выбранную информацию из БД в документ?
ПОжалуйста, направьте меня в нужное русло... очень нужно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

чекбоксы выводи следующим образом

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="4" />
```

У тебя в POST запросе будет формироваться автомассив $_POST['selected']. В обработчике через foreach пробежись по массиву, чтобы обработать каждое значение и выполнить с ним определенное действие